# Filter values from jCombobox

Tags: java, sql, jcombobox

How do you filter text in jcombobox.
The jComboBox is populated by sql select.
Need to filter with editable jcombobox

Comment: Need more details. Post your code.

Comment: You want to filter already populated comboBox or you want to load values into it from the database based on what they type into the editor?

Comment: I want to be able to filter already loaded data into the combobox

Comment: You should not populate ComboBox directly from SQL database. You should use ComboBox Model. And the use AutoCompleteDecorator to filter through ComboBox items.